# ¿Como guardar un dato de mi app y que no se pueda borrar?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Estoy desarrollando una app en la que se guardan los datos del usuario con `SharedPreferences`, el problema es que si el usuario desinstala o elimina los datos de la aplicación los datos desaparecen, estos datos son de extremanda importancia Alguien sabe como guardar estos datos y que no se puedan eliminar para Android.

En esta información viene la contraseña para desencriptar información del usuario, ¿Que es mejor guardar la contraseña en DB Local o DB Online?

Comment: Nada que sea local te va a funcionar puesto que cada vez que desinstalen la app se borrará la bd

Comment: entonces guardo la contraseña de desencriptado en DB?

Comment: No seria muy peligroso, ya que la información encriptada estaría junto a la clave de desencriptación o seria bueno encriptar la contraseña tambien?

Comment: Renta un servidor de base de datos, problema resuelto

Comment: Escribe en la sdcard del telfono en un lugar donde no se borre, por ejemplo la carpeta fotos o movies.

Comment: Lo mejor es guardarla en backend porque si el user desinstala la app o cambia de móvil perderá esos datos... si eso es un problema no sé si se podría usar FileProvider y guardar la info encriptada en el propio dispositivo fuera del ámbito de la app.

Answer (score 0):

**Si estas usando cualquiera de las [opciones de almacenamiento de android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=es-419), estos datos no son persistentes si el usuario elimina la información, caché o la aplicación.**

Si deseas tener información persistente es obtenerla a través de un medio externo, para que de esta forma si no existe la información la obtenga nuevamente.

Se recomienda que si usas información sensible esta sea encriptada y consultada mediante un Web Service externo o descargando una base de datos que solo el usuario con las credenciales necesarias pueda desencriptar la información en este caso puedes usar:

[**SQLCipher for Android**](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/)

Revisa las opciones criptográficas que ofrece android:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography
https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary